# How to re-run through loop when exception happens in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

When executing this it only runs through the initial if elif statement. If I reach 0 it returns the proper print statement along with when I'm subtracting numbers. However if I try to subtract to reach a negative number and therefore reach the exception, it doesn't print the statement below and reloop through like I want it to.

```
number = 15
print("Subtract the number", number, "until it has reached 0")
while number != 0:
    try:
        x = int(input())
        number = number-x
        if number > 0:
            print("You have", number, "points to spend!")
        elif number == 0:
            print("You have used all your points!")
            break
    except number < 0:
            print("You don't have enough points for that!")
            continue
```

Comment: This is not an exception! Just change the `except number <0` to `else`.

Comment: `except` should be used to catch the error if the input isn't an integer. `except ValueError: print("Type an integer"); continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except` is used for catching errors. You want this:

```
while number != 0:
    x = int(input())
    if number - x > 0:
        number -= x
        print("You have", number, "points to spend!")
    elif number == x:
        number = 0
        print("You have used all your points!")
        break
    else:
        print("You don't have enough points for that!")
```